# how to get unique values in array and append them into a select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects `[{COUNTRY_NAME: "xxx", COUNTRY_CODE: "xxx"},...]`

I want to get the unique values of `COUNTRY_NAME` and append the values into a `select`, the same for `COUNTRY_CODE`

What I did is :

First I loop through all my selects `$("select").each` then I get the id of the current select `var id = $(this).attr("id");`

Then I create an array with unique values of that key `let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.COUNTRY_NAME))];` The problem is here when I use `item => item.id` it does not recognize id as key in `data`.

at the end, I add the unique values as options inside each select.

How can I say in jQuery that `id` is a variable key so that `item.id` will vary based on the current value and it's not a key called `id` in my `data` array ?

Any suggestions please ? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

var data = [{COUNTRY_NAME: "Austria", COUNTRY_CODE: "AT"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Austria", COUNTRY_CODE: "AT"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium", COUNTRY_CODE: "BE"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Croatia", COUNTRY_CODE: "HR"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Croatia", COUNTRY_CODE: "HR"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "France", COUNTRY_CODE: "FR"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Austria", COUNTRY_CODE: "AT"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Austria", COUNTRY_CODE: "AT"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "France", COUNTRY_CODE: "FR"}];

 $("select").each(function() {
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
 console.log(id);
 
 //when I use item.COUNTRY_NAME or item.COUNTRY_CODE it works
 //but when I use item.id where id will get the current value I want to map it shows undefined.
//The problem is : it can't find a key id in data
 
 //let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.id))];
 
 let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.COUNTRY_NAME))];
 console.log(unique);
 
var $mySelect = $(this);
$.each(unique, function(key, value) {
  var $option = $("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
  });
  $mySelect.append($option);
});
 
 
 
 });
 
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h5>COUNTRY NAME</h5>
<select id = "COUNTRY_NAME" multiple></select>
<h5>COUNTRY CODE</h5>
<select id = "COUNTRY_CODE" multiple></select>
```

Comment: Bootstrap-select along with datatables was, actually, a nice choice (of jQuery-based solution). If you wanted to populate your table entries dynamically (fetched from backend) and the number of records does not exceed few thousands, you could avoid using `serverSide: true` and make use of `ajax` option. Would solution like that be still of interest for you?

Comment: If you need to access dynamically properties of objects inside `data`, based on attribute of `<select>`, you may simply use bracket notation, i.e. `let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item[id]))]`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Thank you very much it works with bracket now :)